# Как исправить ошибку обучения на Keggle? (loss растет хотя на google colab сеть обучается нормально)

Tags: python, tensorflow, искусственный-интеллект, google-colaboratory, kaggle

Ошибка заключается вот в чем. Это процесс обучения нейросети на kaggle:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот как выглядит обучение на google colab:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в google colab нейронка обучается нормально то в Kaggle этот процесс протекает неадекватно (Loss это прекрасно демонстрирует).
Код в обоих примерах идентичный, ниже приведены ссылки на оба проекта.

Google colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1klHVZMy4H3VTRdDjkGodiiHIYGFbLZWp?usp=sharing

Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexandrgrigorenko/32x32

Answer (score 0):

Переключаетесь с A100 на x2 T4. Души не чаю как это работает но обучение на этих видеокартах протекает нормально.